# Замена значения между первыми слешами

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.
Есть такая строка.
"/de/tracker/05202045051112657859"
Каким образом(возможно через регулярные выражения) в ней можно заменить значение находящееся, только между двумя первыми слешами?(de)
Заменить к примеру на значение(en).
И привести конечное выражение к виду:
"/en/tracker/05202045051112657859"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Regex Cheat Sheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

```js
let str = "/de/tracker/05202045051112657859";

console.log( ex1(str) );
console.log( ex2(str) );
console.log( ex3(str) );

function ex1(str) {
  return str.replace(/\/.*?\//, "/bubu/");
}

function ex2(str) {
  return str.split(/\/.*?\//).join("/bubu/");
}

function ex3(str) {
  let _1st = str.indexOf('/');
  let _2nd = str.indexOf('/', _1st + 1);
  
  return str.slice(0, _1st) + "/bubu/" + str.slice(_2nd + 1);
}
```